# ASP .NET Application_Start Event + Connection to a DB

Tags: asp.net, application-start, dbconnection

I have started developing a full-web application by using the ASP .NET MVC 3 framework.
I am a MVC 3 beginner developer.

On the server-side I am going to execute some queries to a DB.
Consequently I will have to make a connection to the DB.

I would like to know if it is better to make a connection in the beginning of each action method or in an event handler.
I have thought about making the connection in the Application_Start event handler and then storing an object representing my connection into the application state.
Does this way present disadvantages ?

Thanks in advance for your future answer

Comment: It won't work: a database connection is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open and close the connection as required (rather than keeping one open). Let connection pooling work for you.

[10 Tips for Writing High-Performance Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx) (ASP.NET but contains relevant advice):

> **Tip 3—Connection Pooling**
>
> Setting up the TCP connection between your Web application and SQL
>   Server™ can be an expensive operation. Developers at Microsoft have
>   been able to take advantage of connection pooling for some time now,
>   allowing them to reuse connections to the database. Rather than
>   setting up a new TCP connection on each request, a new connection is
>   set up only when one is not available in the connection pool. When the
>   connection is closed, it is returned to the pool where it remains
>   connected to the database, as opposed to completely tearing down that
>   TCP connection.