# How to access EF to SQL Server Compact stored in App_Data folder during Application_Start

Tags: entity-framework, permissions, sql-server-ce, odata

I have a basic .NET 4 website. It contains an Entity Framework model which maps to a SQL Server Compact database which I store in the `App_Data` folder.

I've added an OData service to the website and I expose the entities and it all works fine, I can publish to my shared hosting and read/write to the database without problems.

However, I want to access the data in my database during `Application_Start` (to create a small search index). When I create an instance of the Entity Framework context at that point in the application life cycle, it throws an exception that it doesn't have access to the database. It works fine locally, just a problem when I publish to my shared hosting.

Normally I'd think this is just a straight permissions problem, but the OData service is working fine, so that must be executing with different permissions than the code that executes in `Application_Start`...

Has anyone seen this before or have any ideas what might be going on?

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
  at System.Data.SqlServerCe.UnmanagedLibraryHelper..ctor(String fileName)
  at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethodsHelper..ctor(String modulePath)
  at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadValidLibrary(String modulePath)
  at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinariesFromPrivateFolder(String privateInstall)
  at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinaries()
  at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection..ctor()
  at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory.CreateConnection()
  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetStoreConnection(DbProviderFactory factory)
  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
  at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
  at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName)
  at LDS.Model1Container..ctor() in *REMOVED*\LDS\Model1.Designer.cs:line 40
  at LDS.Global.BuildIndex() in *REMOVED*\LDS\Global.asax.cs:line 38
```

Comment: There was a comment to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800696/asp-net-application-start-event-connection-to-a-db about not being thread safe.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the pointer. In this instance, i'm not trying to keep a connection alive outside the scope of Application_Start, i'm just wanting to iterate over some data and build an in memory search index (which is thread safe).

Comment: I've tried a couple of different things now. The problem can be simplified to not include SQL Compact at all. I've changed my code to try and write a txt file with a basic StreamWriter to the App_Data folder during Application_Start and it errors due to insufficient access. The same line of code writes the file file when from a button click handler on a webpage in the same website.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i think i've worked it out.

When the application starts, it's running under the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE account.

When a normal web request comes in, it's executed using an *\IUSR_* account.

On my shared hosting, the NETWORK SERVICE account clearly doesn't have write access to the App_Data folder, but the IUSR account does.

I think that answers the question as to why the problem is occurring.